Django cookiecutter docker backups not working
I have a django cookiecutter docker project and It's on github. I have it on my windows laptop and on the company's windows server. The backups are working fine on my laptop when I do docker compose -f production.yml exec postgres backup but on the windows server the terminal seems to freeze up, it just stops and looks like nothing is happening.
On my laptop it looks like this
PS C:\work\*******\*******> docker compose -f production.yml exec postgres backup 
Backing up the 'app' database...
SUCCESS: 'app' database backup 'backup_2024_04_03T19_13_30.sql.gz' has been created and placed in '/backups'.
PS C:\work\*******\*******> 

on the windows server it looks like this.
PS C:\work\*******\*******> docker compose -f production.yml exec postgres backup 

Also i am sure i have the same version of my project on both of them
